# XML Deserialize camt.053.001.04 field problem

Tags: c#, xml

I do not know how to handle multiple XML Tags with the same name without doing arrays or List.

**Original XML wihtout content:**

```
`<Document xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.04">
<BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>
        <MsgId></MsgId>
        <CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
        <MsgPgntn>
        <PgNb></PgNb>
        <LastPgInd></LastPgInd>
        </MsgPgntn>
    </GrpHdr>
<Stmt>
<Id></Id>
<ElctrncSeqNb></ElctrncSeqNb>
<CreDtTm></CreDtTm>
<FrToDt>
 <FrDtTm></FrDtTm>
 <ToDtTm></ToDtTm>
</FrToDt>
<Acct>
    <Id>
    <IBAN></IBAN>
    </Id>
    <Ccy></Ccy>
    <Ownr>
    <Nm></Nm>
    <PstlAdr>
    <AdrLine></AdrLine>
    <AdrLine></AdrLine>
    </PstlAdr>
    </Ownr>
    <Svcr>
    <FinInstnId>
    <BICFI></BICFI>
    <Nm></Nm>
    </FinInstnId>
    </Svcr>
</Acct>
<Bal></Bal>
<Bal></Bal>
<Ntry></Ntry>
<Ntry></Ntry>
<Ntry></Ntry>
</BkToCstmrStmt></Document>`
```

**Now im at AdrLine.** Normaly i would think its something like `string[] AdrLine`.
But that is not the case here. `string[]` would generate following:
`<AdrLine><string></string><string></string></AdrLine>`

I know AdrLine must be a class or struct to achiev that structure. So i tested around with that but stuck at multiple lines and value without using array or list. What i currnently have is: `<PstlAdr><AdrLine /></PstlAdr>` If someone can enlighten me, that would be great pleasure. The Achievment should look like this: `<PstlAdr><AdrLine>Line1</AdrLine><AdrLine>Line2</AdrLine></PstlAdr>`

At the `<Bal></Bal><Bal></Bal>` or `<Ntry></Ntry><Ntry></Ntry>` i have the same Issue. Normaly i would think this is in a Array, but here this isn't the case too cause of the missing Array Tags around the `<Bal></Bal>` or `<Ntry></Ntry>` tags.

**Serialize method with Generictype:**

```
public static readonly string defaultFilePath = Application.StartupPath;
public static readonly string fileFormat = "xml";
public static void SaveAs<T>(T obj, string filename, string xmlNamespace = "")
        {
            string filePath = defaultFilePath + "/" + filename + "." + fileFormat;
            using (FileStream outFile = File.Create(filePath))
            {
                if (File.Exists(filePath))
                {
                    XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType(), xmlNamespace);
                    xmlSerializer.Serialize(outFile, obj);
                }
                else { throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found", filename); }
            }
        }
```

**My Testing Implementation:**

```
BankDesign.Camt.Document document = new BankDesign.Camt.Document();
            document.BkToCstmrStmt = new BkToCstmrStmt();
            document.BkToCstmrStmt.GrpHdr = new BankDesign.Camt.GrpHdr(1233215, DateTime.UtcNow, new MsgPgntn(123546, false));
            document.BkToCstmrStmt.Stmt = new Stmt();
            document.BkToCstmrStmt.Stmt.Acct = new Acct();
            
           AdrLine[] lines = new AdrLine[2];
            AdrLine AdrLine = new AdrLine();
            AdrLine.Name = "Test";
            lines[0] = AdrLine;
            AdrLine = new AdrLine();
            AdrLine.Name = "Test2";
            lines[1] = AdrLine;

            document.BkToCstmrStmt.Stmt.Acct.Ownr = new Ownr("Test", new PstlAdr(lines));

            FileManager.SaveAs<Document>(document, "Camt05300104", "urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.04");
```

**Camt05300104 Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Document xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:camt.053.001.04">
  <BkToCstmrStmt>
    <GrpHdr>
      <MsgId>1233215</MsgId>
      <CreDtTm>2023-02-07T10:57:07.2314082Z</CreDtTm>
      <MsgPgntn>
        <PgNb>123546</PgNb>
        <LastPgInd>false</LastPgInd>
      </MsgPgntn>
    </GrpHdr>
    <Stmt>
      <Id>0</Id>
      <ElctrncSeqNb>0</ElctrncSeqNb>
      <CreDtTm>0001-01-01T00:00:00</CreDtTm>
      <FrToDt>
        <FrDtTm>0001-01-01T00:00:00</FrDtTm>
        <ToDtTm>0001-01-01T00:00:00</ToDtTm>
      </FrToDt>
      <Acct>
        <Id />
        <Ownr>
          <Nm>Test</Nm>
          <PstlAdr>
            <AdrLine><Name>Test</Name></AdrLine>
            <AdrLine><Name>Test2</Name></AdrLine>
          </PstlAdr>
        </Ownr>
      </Acct>
    </Stmt>
  </BkToCstmrStmt>
</Document>
```

**The Camt Classes for Deserialize**

```
//camt.053.001.04
namespace BankDesign.Camt
{
    public struct PstlAdr
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public AdrLine[] AdrLine;

        public PstlAdr(AdrLine[] adrLine)
        {
            AdrLine = adrLine;
        }
    }

    public class AdrLine
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AdrLine() { }
    }
}
```

Comment: Btw.: please try to nail your question down to a simple, short sample, that represents your issue. It's not needed to post your entire class-structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems i found a solution that worked for me.

```
    public struct PstlAdr
    {
        [XmlElement()]
        public AdrLine[] AdrLine;

        public PstlAdr(AdrLine[] adrLine)
        {
            AdrLine = adrLine;
        }
    }

    public class AdrLine
    {
        [XmlText()]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public AdrLine() { }
    }
```

Found at:
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlelement?view=net-7.0 and
https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmltext?view=net-7.0